# Как поделить на куски Ruby GraphQL Functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

Есть множество функций (`GraphQL::Function`), в которых используются одни и те же части кода.

Если бы речь шла о Rails моделях, то я бы воспользовался `ActiveSupport::Concern`. Ну или еще каким-нибудь способом, будь то даже корневой `ApplicationRecord` класс для описания общих методов.

Но что касается GraphQL, то я не понимаю как реализовать подобное.

Например, у меня есть методы, которые приходится дублировать в каждый класс функции. Вот хотя бы на таком простом примере можете мне, пожалуйста, объяснить, как правильно поступить (оптимизировать код)? Я честно не увидел что-то похожее в документации к GraphQL Ruby...

Пример функций:

```
class Functions::GetSomething < GraphQL::Function
    attr_reader :type

    def initialize(one:, two:, type:)
        @one = one
        @two = two
        @type = type
    end

    argument :id, !types.Int

    def call(_obj, args, ctx)
        # Some code
        some_method('ruby', 'rails')
        # Some code
    rescue StandardError => error
        GraphQL::ExecutionError.new(error)
    end

    private

    def some_method(value1, value2)
    end
end
```

Comment: Приведите код с дублированием и опишите, что именно хотите вытащить. Будем думать.

Comment: @D-side обычный класс функции GraphQL. Ничем не отличается от того примера, что в документации - http://graphql-ruby.org/fields/function.html. Метод находится в `private` этого класса и вызывается из `call`. В метод передаются два параметра. В методе что-то-то делается и в итоге что-то отдается.

Comment: Напоминаю, что детали о вопросе необходимо добавлять *непосредственно* в вопрос (не ссылки, а сами детали).

Comment: @D-side я не могу публиковать здесь этот код.

Comment: И не надо. Минимальный пример для демонстрации проблемы не требует копирования существующего кода.

Comment: @D-side добавил.

Comment: Хм. Пока не наблюдаю ничего GraphQL-специфичного, руби как руби. Почему бы не попробовать `ActiveSupport::Concern`?

Comment: @D-side попробовал. `GraphQL::Function` не понимает что такое `Concern`.

Comment: На протяжении целого ряда вопросов я убедился, что вашей интерпретации ошибок верить нельзя. `:D` Давайте само сообщение.

Comment: @D-side :) Я прописываю `include` внутри класса функции и получаю ошибку, мол, класс консерна не найден.

Comment: Так может, его зареквайрить надо?

Comment: @D-side Спасибо. Опять тупеж и прозрение.